# Generating all possible combinations of a small set

Tags: r, resampling

I'd like to generate all the possible combinations of a small data set, say `{2,4,6}`, using the sample function **with replacement** in R.

I'd welcome solutions not involving the sample function as well.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you specifically looking for all [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (aka *bags*) or an enumeration of all tuples (as in @StasK's answer)?

Comment: @Jim, I'm looking for the enumeration of all tuples.Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure how flexible a solution you are looking for, but the brute force one could be

```
expand.grid(first=c(2,4,6),second=c(2,4,6),third=c(2,4,6))
```

For a more flexible solution, you would probably have to accumulate the grids in a cycle if you don't know the number of elements in advance.

Comment: For now I'm dealing with data sets with fixed length. So, your solution will do. Thank you!

Comment: @tcollar For unfixed length, `do.call(expand.grid, replicate(n = length(x), x, simplify = F))`, where `x` is your set.